# ArgumentError in ConversationsController#show -- wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, messaging, actioncontroller

With the **Messageable** gem in my Ruby on Rails app, I can access the New Conversation page successfully and chose a user to send to, a title for the message, and of course the body of the message itself.

However, when I click the send button and the page reloads, I receive the following error message:

```
ArgumentError in ConversationsController#show

wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

Extracted source (around line #4):
2  
3  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
4  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
5    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
6    size = options[:size]
7    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=# {size}"
```

What could be causing this issue? I'm having so many issues with the [New Relic tutorial for Messageable](http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/) I've been following.. I'm not sure if this error perhaps indicates some problem with there being two seperate gravatar methods that were for two different functions & tutorials (*users_helper.rb* gravatar method is implemented for profile pictures, from the Hartl tutorial; *application_helper.rb* gravatar method is implemented for the Messageable new relic tutorial). I don't believe there is any collision between the two causing an error as I haven't been able to fix it yet, but it's a possibility(?)

Anyways, any solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

---

=>**Rails** version: 4.1.2, **Ruby** version: 2.1.4

---

**app/helpers/users_helper.rb**:

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.username, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

---

**Full Backtrace**:

```
app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `gravatar_for'
app/views/conversations/show.html.erb:16:in `block in _app_views_conversations_show_html_erb__1169498260752427397_69885071298420'
app/views/conversations/show.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_conversations_show_html_erb__1169498260752427397_69885071298420'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
rack-timeout (0.2.0) lib/rack/timeout.rb:108:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

---

**application_helper**:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Helper method to easily render Gravatars.
  def gravatar_for(user, size = 30, title = user.username)
    image_tag gravatar_image_url(user.email, size: size), title: title, class: 'img-rounded'
  end
end
```

---

**_participants.html.erb**:

```
<% conversation.participants.each do |participant| %>
  <% unless participant == current_user %>
    <%= gravatar_for participant %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**messages_helper.rb**:

```
module MessagesHelper
  def recipients_options
    s = ''
    User.all.each do |user|
      s << "<option value='#{user.id}' data-img-src='#{gravatar_image_url(user.email, size: 50)}'>#{user.name}</option>"
    end
    s.html_safe
  end
end
```

---

**app/views/conversations/show.html.erb**:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Conversation') %>

<p>Chatting with
  <%= render 'conversations/participants', conversation: @conversation %>
</p>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><%= @conversation.subject %></div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="messages">
      <% @conversation.receipts_for(current_user).each do |receipt| %>
        <div class="media">
          <% message = receipt.message %>
          <div class="media-left">
            <%= gravatar_for message.sender, 45, message.sender.name %>
          </div>

          <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="media-heading"><%= message.sender.name %>
                says at <%= message.created_at.strftime("%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S") %></h6>
            <%= message.body %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add code of *app/views/conversations/show.html* file?

Comment: Sure, I've added *app/views/conversations/show.html.erb* to the bottom of the question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `show` template there is code:

```
<%= gravatar_for message.sender, 45, message.sender.name %>
```

Unfortunately you have defined `gravatar_for` in two helpers - one in your `UsersHelper`, and one in your `ApplicationHelper`.

It looks like the definition from `UsersHelper` takes precedence over `ApplicationHelper`'s one. Try removing the one from `UserHelper`, so the proper method is called.

Good luck!

**EDIT**

You've mentioned you want to be able to customise the `gravatar` size, and it is possible with your current implementation of `UsersHelper#gravatar_for`. Change your code in `show` as follows:

```
<%= gravatar_for message.sender, { size: 45 } %>
```

Please note I removed the third argument so it doesn't cause any errors. Additionally I passed a `hash` with defined `size`.

This should do the trick!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way to see all files at once which utilize the code contained in `UsersHelper`? Since it is currently being used in my application for profile pictures and other things I need to somehow keep it's functionality while also using the `ApplicationHelper`'s `gravatar_for` method for the Messageable system between users... would this be possible at all? (thanks for the help so far by the way)

Comment: Well, it difficult to advise anything for me - I don't know the whole application. Clearly there is a problem with naming collision, and it's easier for you to justify if removing or renaming one of methods is less work. If you are working in unix environment, you can try command `grep -R 'gravatar_for' *`, this will list all files with occurrences of `gravatar_for`. I'm afraid I can't help more at that point...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I guess what I really need to figure out is how to have gravatars with different sizes in different views; size 30 for the messaging system view and size 80 for the profile page picture view. But that's okay if you aren't sure how to have 2 different size avatar pictures defined in different views

Comment: Oh! If this is the case, you can still reuse your `gravatar_for` from `UsersHelper`. I'll update the answer to show you an example!